# Download photos from digital camera to iCloud

Tags: icloud, photos, data-transfer

When I connect my Sony digital camera to my MacBook Air, photos go Dropbox instead of going to iCloud.  I have enough space in my iCloud account, which is almost empty.

Comment: What do you mean by "go to Dropbox"? You plug in the camera and the without further activities from your side the pictures are transfered to Dropbox? Is there an application (by Sony) running in the background? If you open Image Capture.app while the camera is plugged in: is there an application selected to be opened automatically?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you have checked the **Enable camera uploads for:** checkbox in Dropbox Preferences:

[image]